# How to Load previous page on back-button click in Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Load the previous page or (home page) when back button is pressed in meteor.

I have implemented search functionality in meteor app. After getting results when i press the back button it still remains in the same page. I am refreshing the page every time so that it reloads again.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
function serachJob(){
        var search_text=document.getElementById('serachText').value;
        console.log(search_text);
        var search = new RegExp(search_text, 'i');
        searchCriteria={ $or: [{ J_Headline: search },{ J_Location:search  }] };
        _deps.changed();
    }
```

What is the solution for getting to earlier page on clicking back button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manipulate the history object. Read about history.pushState and window.onpopstate here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Or you could just take advantage of other peoples work, and make life easy for, for example by using [iron router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) (requires meteorite).